# Import xml elements into powershell variables

Tags: xml, powershell

I've figured out how to import an xml file into a Powershell variable using the `[xml]` tag before the variable and `Get-Content`, but filling every variable in Powershell from that new xml-formatted variable one at a time is painstaking.

```
$variable = $xml.vars.Linux.variable1
$variable2 = $xml.vars.Linux.variable2
```

... and so on.

Is there a shorter/faster way to just import that xml file and set Powershell variables that match the Node names and fill those variables with the associated Node values? So I don't have to specifically fill every Powershell value with it's corresponding named xml Node, I can just use the Powershell variables without lines of code filling them?

I suspect I may need a loop of some sort...current xml structure is 3 layers with category name for second layer Node and then variable names for Nodes within. For example:

```
<vars>
 <Windows>
  <Hostname>Contoso</Hostname>
  <IP_Address>192.168.1.1</IP_Address>
 </Windows>
 <Linux>
  <variable1>Yup</variable1>
  <variable2>Yessir</variable2>
 </Linux>
</vars>
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you want the variable names to be based on the element names? Or is there some other relationship?

Comment: Exactly! Makes it easier for script writing but puts the values in a separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a variable for each element under a particular node like this:

```
$xml.vars.Linux.ChildNodes | %{ New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $_.InnerText -PassThru}
```

You can remove the `-PassThru` switch to avoid outputting the variables onto the pipeline.

Comment: Ah, that's it! Thank you! I also added the `-force` switch to overwrite any possible values within the named variables.

Answer (score 1):

Is the goal to turn the xml data into powershell objects you can call elsewhere?
Would something like this work for you?

```
foreach ($var in $variable.linux){
                        $properties = @{'variable1'=$var.variable1
                                        'variable2'=$var.variable2}
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $properties -ErrorAction Stop
Write-Output $obj}
```

Comment: Playing with this, this seems very close... though the loop has to get the name of the new Powershell variable from the xml element beneath "variable.linux".... then fill that variable with the value of the xml element. Looks like I have to specifically call out each xml element in this loop currently.

Answer (score 1):

You can access xml nodes really easily in Powershell using xpath. Example:

```
$myNode = $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Linux")
```

From there you can append additional elements on to the node.

First create a new Element

```
$child = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("NewElementName")
```

Second add the value to the new child Element

```
$Child.InnerXML = "ValueHere"
```

Then Append the child element to the node you have selected

```
$myNode.AppendChild($child)
```

This can easily be done in a loop and you'll be working directly with the xml object instead of converting it.